# Change person icon on map using OsmDroid

Tags: java, android, android-mapview, android-bitmap, osmdroid

I am using Osmdroid for the map in an activity, but I cannot change the default icon of a yellow person. Currently what I am trying, but nothing is shown on the map.

```
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_truck);
 mLocationOverlay.setPersonIcon(bitmap);
 map.getOverlays().add(mLocationOverlay);
```

in console this comes out.

```
E/OsmDroid: error dispatchDraw, probably in edit mode
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.isRecycled()' on a null object reference
    at android.graphics.BaseCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(BaseCanvas.java:54)
    at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:226)
    at android.view.RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(RecordingCanvas.java:78)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if you missed some context on your code:
`map.getOverlays().add(mLocationOverlay);`

Here is an example:

```
       //My Location
       //note you have handle the permissions yourself, the overlay did not do it for you
       mLocationOverlay = new MyLocationNewOverlay(new GpsMyLocationProvider(context), mMapView);
       mLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
       Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_menu_compass);
       mLocationOverlay.setPersonIcon(bitmap);
       mMapView.getOverlays().add(this.mLocationOverlay);
```

Where

```
private MyLocationNewOverlay mLocationOverlay;
```